# How do I get normal attributes of an element when selected with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, attributes

I have a textarea which I select using jQuery, and I want to find the position of the cursor within it. I've found that in normal JavaScript you can do it with `.selectionStart`, but doing `$("#maintext").selectionStart` results in `undefined`.

How can I do it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/263743/how-to-get-cursor-position-in-textarea

Comment: @Bing: That's not addressing his problem, because he wants to combine it with a jQuery object.

Comment: @pimvdb, sure but there are mentions of jQuery there too. Figured it'd be a good reference to this question..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`selectionStart` is native DOM property so try this:

```
var selStart = $('#maintext').get(0).selectionStart;
```

The reason for this happening is that `$('#maintext')` returns an array of jQuery wrapped DOM objects and in order to invoke a native method you need to get the underlying element.

Comment: I would rather use `.get(0)`, because it's cleaner and provides negative index support.

Comment: Oh, okay. What does the [0] stand for? The first selected element?

Comment: Probably worth adding that the reason `undefined` was returned is because there was no *specific* DOM element specified by the jQuery selector. So, presumably, `$('#maintext:first').selectionStart;` would've worked, too. @Gabriele, the `[0]` specifies the first element of the array returned by the selector.

Comment: @Gabriele Cirulli, yes, but because you are using an id selector there should always be only one.

Comment: `selectionStart` and `selectionEnd` properties are not supported in IE < 9.

Answer (score 3):

In that situation there might be a case for simply doing:

```
document.getElementById("maintext").selectionStart
```

and not have the overhead of creating a new jQuery object.

Comment: Thanks, but I'd like to keep all the syntax based on jQuery for simplicity and also because speed isn't the main concern.

Comment: Gabriele - if your goal is simplicity (perhaps maintainability is what you meant), then it is better to make it obvious where DOM methods area being used. Mixing jQuery and DOM methods in the one expression is the opposite of that. The problem with the object wrapping approach adopted by jQuery is that it needs to provide an equivalent function for every DOM method, plus getters and setters for every DOM property. The authors seem to have chosen to only duplicate some methods and properties.

Answer (score 0):

In jQuery 1.6, you could use `prop()`. In older versions, `attr()` could be used.

```
$("#maintext").prop("selectionStart");
```

However, `selectionStart` and `selectionEnd` properties are not supported in IE < 9. I've published a cross-browser function to work round this in a few places on Stack Overflow (for example, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/263743/how-to-get-cursor-position-in-textarea/3373056#3373056)), or you could use my [jQuery plug-in](http://code.google.com/p/rangyinputs/) for dealing with textarea/text input selections.